# Performance regression in PostgreSQL 14.3 compared to PostgreSQL 13.7 on the same query

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-13, postgresql-14

I migrated a database from Postgresql 13.7 to Postgresql 14.3 recently, and I saw a x2 execution time in a specific case which I can't understand.
The issue has been seen first on Postgres on Linux, and I reproduced the issue using the following example on macOS with a clean Postgres installed through `brew`.

Here is how to reproduce the setup:

```sql
-- DB Setup
CREATE DATABASE pg_regression_test;

-- Connect to the new DB

-- Table: units
CREATE TABLE units
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

-- Table: events
-- Value is a payload/metadata JSONB field where you can have
-- the id of a related unit. 
-- If it's a unit, then you have a value = {'unit_id': 123}
CREATE TABLE events
(
    action    VARCHAR   NOT NULL,
    value     JSONB,
    timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX events_action_idx ON events (action);

CREATE INDEX events_unit_id_idx ON events ((value ->> 'unit_id')) WHERE (value ? 'unit_id');

-- Materialized view: daily_unit_events
-- Serves: how many similar actions have been made on this unit that day?
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW daily_unit_events AS
SELECT s.id         AS unit_id,
       s.action,
       s.dt,
       SUM(s.count) AS count
FROM (
         WITH t AS (
             SELECT events.value ->> 'unit_id'                  AS unit_id,
                    events.action,
                    DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE AS dt,
                    1                                           AS count
             FROM events
             WHERE events.value ? 'unit_id'
             GROUP BY events.value ->> 'unit_id',
                      events.action,
                      (DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE)
         )
         SELECT units.id,
                t.action,
                t.dt,
                SUM(t.count) AS count
         FROM units
                  JOIN t ON units.id::TEXT = t.unit_id
         GROUP BY units.id, t.action, t.dt
     ) s
GROUP BY s.id, s.action, s.dt;

CREATE INDEX daily_unit_events_unit_id_idx ON daily_unit_events (unit_id);

-- Unique index is mandatory for REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX daily_unit_events_unique_idx ON daily_unit_events (unit_id, action, dt);


-- Data generation
-- Insert 100k units
INSERT INTO units (id)
SELECT i
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100000) s(i);

-- Insert 1M events with a unit_id in the value. Around 20 kind of events. Est: 42s
INSERT INTO events (action, value, timestamp)
SELECT LEFT(MD5(((RANDOM() * 20)::INT)::TEXT), 12)                     AS action,
       JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('unit_id', (RANDOM() * 100000)::INT)         AS value,
       (NOW() - (INTERVAL '1 day' * (RANDOM() * 720)::INT))::TIMESTAMP AS timestamp
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000) s(i);

-- Insert 150k events without a unit_id in the value. Just to be on par with real data.
-- Around 20 kind of other events, distinct from the previous ones. Est: 3s
INSERT INTO events (action, value, timestamp)
SELECT LEFT(MD5(((RANDOM() * 20)::INT + 20)::TEXT), 12)                AS action,
       '{}'::JSONB                                                     AS value,
       (NOW() - (INTERVAL '1 day' * (RANDOM() * 720)::INT))::TIMESTAMP AS timestamp
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 150000) s(i);
```

The issue comes from the materialized view `daily_unit_events`, where the refresh is two times as long on PG14 versus PG13:

```sql
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY daily_unit_events;

-- With test data, once first run is done. (first run is ~2x longer than follow ups)
-- PG 13.7:
--   - completed in 13 s 340 ms
--   - completed in 13 s 436 ms
--   - completed in 12 s 971 ms
--   - completed in 12 s 976 ms
-- PG 14.3:
--   - completed in 24 s 253 ms
--   - completed in 19 s 462 ms
--   - completed in 21 s 941 ms
--   - completed in 24 s 213 ms
```

If you take the query used for the materialized view, you can see the same behavior:

```sql
SELECT s.id         AS unit_id,
       s.action,
       s.dt,
       SUM(s.count) AS count
FROM (
         WITH t AS (
             SELECT events.value ->> 'unit_id'                  AS unit_id,
                    events.action,
                    DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE AS dt,
                    1                                          AS count
             FROM events
             WHERE events.value ? 'unit_id'
             GROUP BY (events.value ->> 'unit_id'), events.action,
                      (DATE_TRUNC('day', events."timestamp")::DATE)
         )
         SELECT units.id,
                t.action,
                t.dt,
                SUM(t.count) AS count
         FROM units
                  JOIN t ON units.id::TEXT = t.unit_id
         GROUP BY units.id, t.action, t.dt
     ) s
GROUP BY s.id, s.action, s.dt;

-- With test data (unit):
-- PG 13.7:
--   - completed in 3 s 355 ms (execution: 3 s 254 ms, fetching: 101 ms)
--   - completed in 3 s 272 ms (execution: 3 s 234 ms, fetching: 38 ms)
--   - completed in 3 s 331 ms (execution: 3 s 303 ms, fetching: 28 ms)
--   - completed in 3 s 332 ms (execution: 3 s 307 ms, fetching: 25 ms)
-- PG 14.3:
--   - completed in 11 s 436 ms (execution: 11 s 392 ms, fetching: 44 ms)
--   - completed in 14 s 520 ms (execution: 14 s 487 ms, fetching: 33 ms)
--   - completed in 12 s 830 ms (execution: 12 s 39 ms, fetching: 44 ms)
--   - completed in 11 s 345 ms (execution: 11 s 314 ms, fetching: 31 ms)
```

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` the previous query outputs:

- PG13:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=5274537.33..13620413.68 rows=5750000 width=53) (actual time=3215.938..4877.993 rows=999667 loops=1)
  Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
  Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=5274537.33..12398538.68 rows=57500000 width=29) (actual time=3215.929..4213.314 rows=999667 loops=1)
        Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
        Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5274537.33..11344372.02 rows=47916666 width=29) (actual time=3215.921..3746.462 rows=999667 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
              ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=5273537.31..5812599.80 rows=23958333 width=29) (actual time=3111.237..3363.517 rows=333222 loops=3)
                    Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
                    ->  Sort  (cost=5273537.31..5333433.14 rows=23958333 width=25) (actual time=3111.218..3177.549 rows=333222 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 15016kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=2985402, temp read=4653 written=4678
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10256kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 11952kB
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=5220.27..617292.54 rows=23958333 width=25) (actual time=90.272..2938.759 rows=333222 loops=3)
                                Merge Cond: (((units.id)::text) = ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)))
                                Buffers: shared hit=2985364
                                ->  Sort  (cost=5218.20..5322.36 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=58.281..63.245 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: ((units.id)::text)
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3257kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=278
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2055kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2278kB
                                      ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using units_pkey on units  (cost=0.29..2020.96 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=0.068..26.356 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                                            Buffers: shared hit=278
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=2.07..132774.67 rows=115000 width=53) (actual time=0.466..2643.878 rows=993712 loops=3)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=2985086
                                      ->  Group  (cost=2.07..131337.17 rows=115000 width=53) (actual time=0.450..2228.330 rows=993712 loops=3)
                                            Group Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=2985086
                                            ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=2.07..122951.83 rows=1003045 width=49) (actual time=0.447..1899.806 rows=994041 loops=3)
                                                  Sort Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                                  Presorted Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text))
                                                  Full-sort Groups: 27025  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=2985086
                                                  Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 26566  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                                  Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 27000  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 27kB  Peak Memory: 27kB
                                                  ->  Index Scan using events_unit_id_idx on events  (cost=0.42..73820.46 rows=1003045 width=49) (actual time=0.101..1184.753 rows=994056 loops=3)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=2985028
Planning Time: 0.435 ms
Execution Time: 4974.368 ms
```

- PG14

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=5272591.23..13616435.63 rows=5748600 width=53) (actual time=9223.276..11004.233 rows=999671 loops=1)
  Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
  Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=5272591.23..12394858.13 rows=57486000 width=29) (actual time=9223.269..10326.712 rows=999671 loops=1)
        Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
        Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=5272591.23..11340948.13 rows=47905000 width=29) (actual time=9223.261..9827.932 rows=999671 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
              ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=5271591.21..5810522.46 rows=23952500 width=29) (actual time=8045.307..8301.748 rows=333224 loops=3)
                    Group Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                    Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
                    ->  Sort  (cost=5271591.21..5331472.46 rows=23952500 width=25) (actual time=8045.284..8115.779 rows=333224 loops=3)
                          Sort Key: units.id, events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17824kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=3002115, temp read=4653 written=4678
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 10640kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 8760kB
                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=5220.24..616523.46 rows=23952500 width=25) (actual time=739.098..7296.621 rows=333224 loops=3)
                                Merge Cond: (((units.id)::text) = ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)))
                                Buffers: shared hit=3002075
                                ->  Sort  (cost=5218.20..5322.36 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=571.336..577.142 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                      Sort Key: ((units.id)::text)
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3613kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=278
                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2107kB
                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1870kB
                                      ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using units_pkey on units  (cost=0.29..2020.96 rows=41667 width=4) (actual time=0.063..15.491 rows=33333 loops=3)
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                                            Buffers: shared hit=278
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=2.05..132122.18 rows=114972 width=53) (actual time=0.434..6303.380 rows=999327 loops=3)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=3001797
                                      ->  Group  (cost=2.05..130685.03 rows=114972 width=53) (actual time=0.425..5882.899 rows=999327 loops=3)
                                            Group Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=3001797
                                            ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=2.05..122329.63 rows=999082 width=49) (actual time=0.423..5532.640 rows=999650 loops=3)
                                                  Sort Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text)), events.action, ((date_trunc('day'::text, events.""timestamp""))::date)
                                                  Presorted Key: ((events.value ->> 'unit_id'::text))
                                                  Full-sort Groups: 27020  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=3001797
                                                  Worker 0:  Full-sort Groups: 26999  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
                                                  Worker 1:  Full-sort Groups: 27023  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 28kB  Peak Memory: 28kB
                                                  ->  Index Scan using events_unit_id_idx on events  (cost=0.42..73541.97 rows=999082 width=49) (actual time=0.049..1407.220 rows=999666 loops=3)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=3001739
Planning Time: 0.269 ms
Execution Time: 11103.528 ms
```

Both query plans are identical, estimated costs and buffers looks the same, but at the end the execution time is more than two times higher.

On macOS, output of `SELECT * FROM pg_config;` is almost identical, they are the defaults when installing from `brew`. The only difference is in the `CFLAGS` entry, where PG14 has been built with an additional `-Werror=unguarded-availability-new` (I stripped down the `*DIR` for conciseness)

```
PGXS,/usr/local/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE, '--disable-debug' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3' '--datadir=/usr/local/share/postgresql' '--libdir=/usr/local/lib' '--includedir=/usr/local/include' '--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc' '--docdir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.3/share/doc/postgresql' '--enable-thread-safety' '--with-gssapi' '--with-icu' '--with-ldap' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--with-openssl' '--with-pam' '--with-perl' '--with-uuid=e2fs' '--with-bonjour' '--with-tcl' 'PG_SYSROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk' 'CC=clang' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include' 'CXX=clang++' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/krb5/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/pkgconfig/11'
CC,clang
CPPFLAGS,-I/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/70.1/include -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include
CFLAGS,-Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Werror=unguarded-availability-new -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro -O2
CFLAGS_SL,""
LDFLAGS,"-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs"
LDFLAGS_EX,""
LDFLAGS_SL,""
LIBS,-lpgcommon -lpgport -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -lreadline -lm
VERSION,PostgreSQL 14.3
```

On the `pg_settings` side, it's also almost identical:

```
-- Common config keys:
server_version,14.3,
server_version_num,140003,
lc_collate,en_US.UTF-8,
lc_ctype,en_US.UTF-8,
lc_messages,en_US.UTF-8,
lc_monetary,en_US.UTF-8,
lc_numeric,en_US.UTF-8,
lc_time,en_US.UTF-8,

server_version,13.7,
server_version_num,130007,
lc_collate,C,
lc_ctype,C,
lc_messages,C,
lc_monetary,C,
lc_numeric,C,
lc_time,C,

-- Only present in one
server_version,13.7,
operator_precedence_warning,off,
vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor,0.1,

server_version,14.3,
client_connection_check_interval,0,ms
compute_query_id,auto,
debug_discard_caches,0,
default_toast_compression,pglz,
enable_async_append,on,
enable_memoize,on,
huge_page_size,0,kB
idle_session_timeout,0,ms
in_hot_standby,off,
log_recovery_conflict_waits,off,
min_dynamic_shared_memory,0,MB
recovery_init_sync_method,fsync,
remove_temp_files_after_crash,on,
ssl_crl_dir,"",
update_process_title,on,
vacuum_failsafe_age,1600000000,
vacuum_multixact_failsafe_age,1600000000,
```

What could be the cause of this performance regression?
Thank you!

Comment: First thing I would do, is to try to get rid of this thing: Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 17824kB. How does your query plan change when you increase work_mem? Try a 100MB or so

Comment: PG14, with `work_mem` set to default `4096kb`, query time is ~12s.
With `work_mem` set to `100MB`, query time is 25s. Result is twice worse.


`work_mem` was the same between PG13 and PG14, and you can see that it's the same `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 15.XXXkB / 17.XXXkB` in the different query plans.

I'm not trying to _optimize_ this query, I'm trying to understand what causes the x2 time spent between the two versions, with the exact same data/query plans.

Comment: Tried with `work_mem` with different values: `2048kb` and `1024kb` gave me an 8s execution time.

Comment: Second thing: `ON units.id::TEXT = t.unit_id` Why do you cast (a Key field) to character? Why not cast the other one to integer? [I know: json ...]

Comment: I still can't reproduce this on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04 with self-compiled dbs) and don't have a Mac to try with.  How did you install on Linux?  Are there any settings which differ between the versions?  How about locale and collations?  Could you show the pg_config output for both (or all four) versions/platforms?

Comment: PG on linux was installed by my platform provider, and I stopped the PG13 one, so I can not provide details for this one.
I will provide the one for my local DB, which are the PG defaults I guess

Comment: @wildplasser because of the existing query which I stripped down for conciseness. Again, we don't care about optimizing the _query_ , but why is there such a difference for the _same query_ on different versions.

Answer (score 2):

Had performance issue migrating from PostgreSQL 10 to PostgreSQL 14 on AWS.

Running the following query did fix the performance issue :

```
VACUUM analyze;
```